# How to clear formatting rules in refresh macro in excel?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a refresh button on a report, and it is tied to a refresh macro. In one of the columns in the report, we have both cell formatting rules and conditional formatting rules for the cell. If the data entered into the column is `1`, the cell will highlight orange, but if 2/3 are entered, it will highlight a different color (under the conditional formatting rules). How do I get my refresh macro to clear the cell formatting rules (if `1` is entered, and refresh is pressed after that?

Current refresh macro:

```
Sub Button6_Click()
With ActiveWorkbook.Connections("pi3db007 BDE _ClaimsReassignment").OLEDBConnection
        .CommandText = "EXEC _ClaimsReassignment "
    ActiveWorkbook.Connections("pi3db007 BDE _ClaimsReassignment").Refresh
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

To clear all **conditional formatting** from a `Sheet`, try using:

```
ActiveSheet.Cells.FormatConditions.Delete
```

Of course, you can change `ActiveSheet` with any `Sheet` you need to clear formatting.

Hope this helps.